# xPath not finding selector when using for-each loop variable, but works otherwise

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, xpath, arraylist

I'm using Selenium to loop through an `ArrayList` of Strings in order to use each string in an xPath expression in order to select its appropriate checkbox on a website.

The problem is, when I use the `for` loop, the variable containing the string doesn't seem to create a valid xPath, yet when I simply substitute the string in myself it works fine.

For example, here is my `ArrayList` declaration with some values added.

```
ArrayList<String> fieldList = new ArrayList<String>();
fieldList.add("Street");
fieldList.add("City");
fieldList.add("Country");
```

If I then use the following code, it goes into the `catch` block

```
WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1);
for (String cField: fieldList) {
    try {
        waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[following-sibling::td[2] = " + cField + "]/input")));
        WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[following-sibling::td[2] = " + cField + "]/input"));
        checkBox.click();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't find " + cField);
    }
}
```

Telling me it couldn't find `"Street"` for example.

Yet when my `try` block contains the following, with the value explicitly stated, it works:

```
waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[following-sibling::td[2] = 'Street']/input")));
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[following-sibling::td[2] = 'Street']/input"));
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the future, you should include the exception that was thrown, as it generally makes it easier to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Will do Tyler. I'm guessing that would be in the variable "error" above? And I access it by System.out.println(error). I can just try it out, but thanks.

Comment: You can do `error.printStackTrace();`, it will show the full stack trace with all error messages. If you want the main error message as a `String`, use `String myExactExceptionMsg = error.getMessage();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to quote your strings in the XPath expression. Add single quotes around `cField`:

```
waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
                     By.xpath("//td[following-sibling::td[2] = '" + cField + "']/input")));
   //                                     quotes added here ---^  and here ---^
WebElement checkBox =
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[following-sibling::td[2] = '" + cField + "']/input"));
   //                                      quotes added here ---^  and here ---^
```

Comment: Duh!! Man.. thank you. I'm still learning proper syntax. This seems like it would be called nested quotes or something. Regardless, thank you. I'll give the checkmark once 10 minutes elapses.